# How to add new page in pdf for multiple record iTextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have an xml and mapping to pdf form field using iTextsharp. It works well for single record. But when multiple records are there, it does not add 2nd record in the output pdf. Here is a code

```
public static void GeneratePdf(string sin, List<XElement> elements)
        {
            var pdfTemplate = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/input.pdf");

            var newFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/output.pdf");

            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
            var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(
                newFile, FileMode.Create));

            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                foreach (var elem in elements.Elements())
                {
                    pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(elem.Name.ToString(), (string)elem);
                }
            }

            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
            pdfStamper.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear because you're telling us nothing about the nature of your form.

**IF YOU'RE FORM IS BASED ON ACROFORM TECHNOLOGY**

Please take a look at this video tutorial: http://itextpdf.com/codenvy_webapp

You can find the examples used in this tutorial here: https://github.com/blowagie/itextsamples

You can also find the standalone examples here: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting

Note that there's an example "HOW NOT TO DO IT". Make sure you use the correct example: [FillFlattenMerge2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge2)

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
PdfReader reader;
PdfStamper stamper;
AcroFields fields;
while (myApp.hasMoreRecords()) {
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
    stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
    fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
    myApp.processNextRecord(fields);
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    // add the PDF to PdfCopy
    reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
    copy.addDocument(reader);
    reader.close();
}
document.close();
```

Note that `myApp` is an instance of a custom class you could write to loop over a record set. You'd implement a method `hasMoreRecords()` and `processNextRecord()` to loop over the records and process them one by one.

**IF YOUR FORM IS BASED ON THE XML FORMS ARCHITECTURE**

In this case, you're using the wrong methods. You can't fill out a dynamic form using the `setField()` method. The fact that it works for one record is a sign that your form is either an AcroForm or a hybrid XFA form. In both cases **you can NOT achieve what you want** without changing your form into a pure, dynamic XFA form.

As soon as you have a pure, dynamic XFA form, you need to use this code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
        new FileOutputStream(dest));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream(xml));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

I repeat: this code snippet will only work if you have a correct form. Elements in your question indicate that this is not the case. If your form isn't a dynamic XFA form, you won't find any software that can achieve what you want!!!

Watch these movies for more info: http://itextpdf.com/product/xfa_worker

Comment: Thanks for reference example. Actually, I have pdf that contain a form. I am able to map xml with the form field for a single record. Now If I have a multiple records, I want to repeat that form for a next record. I tried the above snippet but get an exception when it tried to add new document copy.addDocument(reader); Any suggestion?

Comment: That's not possible when using AcroForms. You need an XFA form. Do you have an XFA form? That's not clear, because you're using the code to fill out an AcroForm. Do you know the difference between AcroForms and XFA forms?

Comment: No, I don't know the difference between them. I can share with you, if you want.

Comment: You can only achieve what you're describing if you have a dynamic XFA form. If you don't have a dynamic XFA form (or worse: if you don't know what a dynamic XFA form is), you are beyond help. In that case, you should start reading the documentation. For instance: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=165 Use this link if you need C# examples: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C08

Comment: I've updated my answer and I sincerely hope you'll watch the movies so that you gain an understanding about the difference between static forms and dynamic forms.

Comment: I can not find a method getAcroFields() on the form. Any idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47176/discussion-between-bruno-lowagie-and-user2866746)